# Working with DispatchQueue in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using dispatcQueue to automatically dismiss my controller but I have an issue is that it dismiss my view controller automatically but also dismiss other view controllers that are presented modally and I want to dismiss only a single view controller

```
func dismissViewController() {
    let pickVc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "request-VC") as! RequestViewController
    pickVc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    pickVc.requestDelegate = self
    present(pickVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openRequestAlertViewController() {
    let pickVc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "requestAlertVC") as! RequestAlertViewController
    pickVc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    pickVc.searchDelegate = self
    present(pickVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func dismissRequestVC() {
    let searchVc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searching-VC") as! SearchingViewController
    searchVc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    present(searchVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but it also dismiss after 20 seconds and I don't want to dismiss this. any help? This is my whole code

Comment: if you want to do that, you CAN NOT display it on controller you want to remove. Imagine you are drawing a picture on a paper and then want to remove paper and expect that drawing will still be there without paper

Comment: but I am using this controller to pass data is there any alternate

Comment: Yes, you can use previous controller to present this picker, and pass data with delegate to this one that will not be dismissed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance for a particular viewcontroller which you want to dismiss like the following

```
var lvc: LoadingViewController?

func showLoadingIn(viewController: UIViewController) {
   lvc = LoadingViewController() // create new instance before presentation
   viewController.presentViewController(lvc!, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func dismissLoader() {
    lvc?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        print("Dismissing Loader view Controller") 
    }
}
```

Comment: why we need to create an instance

Comment: so that it will dismiss that particular viewcontroller

Comment: I understand but I want to dismiss it after few seconds so where can I set the time or no need to set time?

Comment: no need to use timer. Try and let me know whether it is working or not

Comment: not working is there any alternate at the place of DispatchQueue because I have to change a lot if I use your code

Comment: Can u send your project?

Comment: sorry its confidential :/

Comment: I have told you to do the same like yourViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        print("Dismissing Loader view Controller") 
    }

Comment: It is working right then y do u want to go for dispatchQueue?

Answer (score 1):

You are presenting all viewControllers with the current viewController and while dismissing you are are not dismissing the currently presented viewController. Instead you are dismissing the `presenter` viewController so all the presented ViewControllers are also getting dismissed.

If you want to dismiss a particular viewController you can do it like this,

```
yourViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For example in your case you can do this to dismiss the `pickVc` after 20 seconds

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) {
    pickVc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: @viper on what line?

Comment: on pickVc.dismiss

Comment: In `openRequestAlertViewController ` use the same `viewController` name you are using in `present(pickVc, animated: true, completion: nil)`.

Comment: thanks for helping but I don't have enough reputation to upvote